When I implement IEnumerable in class it doesn't get data through fetch api
I want use foreach for list in C# in controller Create([FromBody] CardList cards). I get the error Type 'WordStudy.Models.CardList' can only be used in 'foreach' statements if it implements 'IEnumerable' or 'IEnumerable', or if it has a suitable 'GetEnumerator' method whose return type has a 'Current' property and a 'MoveNext' method. When I implemented IEnumerable in my class it gets null.
script.js
var currentCardNumber = 1;

function addCard() {

    currentCardNumber++;
    let newCardHTML = `
                    <div class="header d-flex justify-content-between p-3">
                        <h4 class="card-counter">${currentCardNumber}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body row">
                        <div class="term col">
                            <h3>Term</h3>
                            <input class="form-control w-100" name = "term" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="definition col">
                            <h3>Definition </h3>
                            <input class="form-control w-100" name="definition" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div> `;
    let newCard = document.createElement('div');
    newCard.classList.add('card');
    newCard.classList.add('mt-3');
    newCard.innerHTML = newCardHTML;

    let addNewCard = document.querySelector('.cards');
    let referenceNode = document.getElementById('create-cards');
    addNewCard.insertBefore(newCard, referenceNode);

}
function saveCardDataToServer() {
    let cards = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('.cards > .card   ').forEach((card) => {

        let termInput = card.querySelector('input[name="term"]');
        let definitionInput = card.querySelector('input[name="definition"]');

        if (termInput && definitionInput) {
            let term = termInput.value.trim();
            let definition = definitionInput.value.trim();
            cards.push({
                Term: term,
                Definition: definition
            });
        }
        else {
            console.error("Input elements not found in card:", card);
        }
    })

    fetch('/Cards/Create/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({Cards: cards})
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data => {
            if (data.success) {
                console.log("Data successfully saved: ", data);
                window.location.href = "/Cards/Learning";
            } else {
                console.error("Error saving card: ", data.message);
            }
        }))
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let newCard = document.querySelector('.new-card');
  newCard.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addCard();
  });
  document.querySelector('form.cards').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    saveCardDataToServer();
  });
});

View
@model CardList

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="~/js/script.js">
    </script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous" asp-append-version="true">    
</head>

<body>

<main class="main">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="new-module d-flex justify-content-between mt-5">
            <h1>Create new module</h1>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Cards" asp-action="learning" type="submit">Создать</a>
        </div>

        <div class="card mt-5 p-2 pb-3">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <input class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Enter a name">
        </div>
        <form asp-controller="Cards" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="cards">
            <div class="card mt-6" id="card">
                <div class="header d-flex justify-content-between p-3">
                    <h4 class="card-counter">1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body row">
                    <div class="term col">
                        <h3>Term</h3>
                        <input class="form-control w-100" name = "term" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="definition col">
                        <h3>Definition </h3>
                        <input class="form-control w-100" name = "definition"  >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Create" id="create-cards" class="btn btn-primary mt-2"/>
        </form>
        <button class="new-card w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4 mt-s rounded-2" style="height: 5rem"  type="button">
            <h3>+ Add card</h3>
        </button>
  </div>

</main>
</body>

</html>

Models
public class Card
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Term { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Definition { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class CardList
{
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}

CardList's model with implemented IEnumerable.
public class CardList : IEnumerable<Card>
{
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    public CardList()
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();
    }
    
    public IEnumerator<Card> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Cards.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

Controller. When I implement IEnumerable CardList cards get null in Create.
public class CardsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Learning()
    {
        var cards = CardsRepository.GetCards();
        return View(cards);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Cards/Create/")]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] CardList cards)
    
    {
        if (cards != null)
        {
            foreach (var card in cards)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(card.Term) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(card.Definition))
                {
                    CardsRepository.AddCard(card);
                }

            }

            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Card saved successfully " });
        }

        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Validation error", errors = errors });
    }

When I delete IEnumerable CardList card get data, however I cannot use foreach.


I want use foreach for list in C#. I get the error Type
'WordStudy.Models.CardList' can only be used in 'foreach' statements
if it implements 'IEnumerable' or 'IEnumerable', or if it has a
suitable 'GetEnumerator' method whose return type has a 'Current'
property and a 'MoveNext' method. When I implemented IEnumerable in my
class it gets null.

According to your shared code snippet I have tried to reroduced your issue at my end and found that, you have two class as following:

Note: As you can see because of two ambiguous class name no enumerable result has been generated. Because compiler doesn't know which class to override.
public class CardList
{
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}

and
public class CardList : IEnumerable<Card>
{
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    public CardList()
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();
    }
    
    public IEnumerator<Card> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Cards.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

Its not clear how  and what you are returning from your var cards = CardsRepository.GetCards();. But I have firstly, tried to return List<Card> but as you have two  class CardList and CardList : IEnumerable<Card> which causing the null data within enumeration because its not clear how you are managing them wihtin your CardsRepository.
However, I have tried as following and getting the expected output:
My Controller:
public IActionResult Learning()
{
    var cards = CardsRepository.GetCards();
    //return View(cards);

    return Ok(cards);
}

Demo Repository:
public static class CardsRepository
{
    public static CardList GetCards()
    {
        var cardList = new CardList
        {
            Cards = new List<Card>
                {
                    // Populate your CardList with Card objects
                    new Card { CardId = 1, Term = "ExampleTerm1", Definition = "ExampleDefinition1" },
                    new Card { CardId = 2, Term = "ExampleTerm2", Definition = "ExampleDefinition2" }
                  
                }
        };
        return cardList;
    }
}

Demo Enumeration Class:
public class CardList : IEnumerable<Card>
{
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    public CardList()
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Card> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Cards.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

Note: Keep in mind if you have two same name class of CardList remove the earlier one and keep CardList : IEnumerable<Card> this would resolve your issue. Your CardList has override CardList : IEnumerable<Card> and  Cards.GetEnumerator() hasn't been called which causing null enumeration result. Also you haven't shared repository details, So remove the CardList which would resolve your null result set.
Output:



Note:  In a nutshell, you are encountering this issue because you have two definitions for the CardList class. In C#, having two classes with the same name within the same namespace or within included namespaces can cause conflicts and unexpected behavior. Please refer  this official document.

I am apologize my question was not correct. I mean when I implement IEnumerable<Card> in CardList get null in controller Create([FromBody] CardList cards) and of course I remove CardList without IEnumerable. So, In a nutshell, I get data in controller Create([FromBody] CardList cards) if CardList does not implement IEnumerable. When CardList have IEnumerable I get null in controller.

I see, however, based on your shared code snippet I have provided the correct answer, tough, you have another issue, for null data in controller request, first of all check your browser console or network trace if the data has been sent accordingly.
